# cakephp send mail asks for old template convention

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.5.3, I'm sending two mails on the controller like this..

```
    function coupon(){

            $this->set('classType','comun cupon');

            if(!empty($this->request->data)){

                $data = $this->request->data;

                $valid = false;

                $errorMessage = 'Asegúrese de ingresar los datos correctamente';

                $this->Paris->set($data);

                if($this->Paris->validates()){

                    $valid = true;

                }



                if($valid){



                    $data['Paris']['coupon'] = strtoupper($data['Paris']['coupon']);



                    //Check if the coupon is free

                    $coupon = $this->Coupon->find('first',array(

                        'conditions' => array(

                            'Coupon.coupon'=> $data['Paris']['coupon'],

                            'AND'=>array(

                                'Coupon.registered' => 0

                            )

                        )

                    ));
                    //$coupon = true;

                    if($coupon){

                         If the query worked then save the row and set registered field to 1

                        $this->Paris->save($data);

                        $q = "UPDATE coupons SET registered = 1 WHERE coupon = '{$data['Paris']['coupon']}' LIMIT 1";

                        if(is_array($this->Coupon->query($q))){


                            //Send the email
                            $parisEmail=new CakeEmail('paris');

                            $parisEmail->from(array($data['Paris']['email'] => 'Nuevo participante registrado - '. $data['Paris']['name'] . ' ' . $data['Paris']['surname']));
                            $parisEmail->viewVars(array('data'=>array(
                                $data['Paris']
                            )));
                            //$parisEmail->transport('Debug');
                            //Check whether it was sent or not

//FIRST EMAIL
                            if($parisEmail->send())
                            {

                                //Send the email
                                $parisUserEmail = new CakeEmail('parisUser');
                                $parisUserEmail->to(array($data['Paris']['email'] => $data['Paris']['name']));
                                $parisUserEmail->from(array($data['Paris']['email'] => $data['Paris']['name'] . ' ' . $data['Paris']['surname']));

                                $parisUserEmail->viewVars(array('data'=>array(
                                    $data['Paris']
                                )));

                                //$parisUserEmail->transport('Debug');

                                //SECOND MAIL
                                if($parisUserEmail->send())
                                {
                                    $this->Session->setFlash('<span style="color:#009900">Se realizó la inscripción exitosamente</span>','default',array('class'=>'flashMessage'));


                    }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $valid = false;

                            $errorMessage = 'No se pudo enviar el mail a su cuenta';
                        }
                    }else{

                        $valid = false;

                        $errorMessage = 'La inscripción no se pudo realizar, por favor intente nuevamente';

                    }

                }else{

                    $this->Paris->validationErrors['coupon'] = 'El código de cupon es incorrecto o ya fue cargado';

                    $valid = false;

                }

            }

            if(!$valid){

                $this->Session->setFlash($errorMessage,'default',array('class'=>'flashMessage'));

            }

        }

    }
```

Yes, the code is a bit large, sorry for that.
Now, here's the problem, I have two templates created for those emails: "paris.ctp" and "parisUser.ctp".

The first mail is sent correctly... however, when it has to send the second mail, it throws this error:

Error:  Confirm you have created the file: C:\wamp\www\kirschbaumarg\trunk\app\View\Emails\html\paris_user.ctp

```
Notice:  If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_view.ctp
Stack Trace
•CORE\Cake\View\View.php line 468 → View->_getViewFileName(string) 
•CORE\Cake\Network\Email\CakeEmail.php line 1684 → View->render(string, string) 
•CORE\Cake\Network\Email\CakeEmail.php line 1537 → CakeEmail->_renderTemplates(string) 
•CORE\Cake\Network\Email\CakeEmail.php line 1148 → CakeEmail->_render(array) 
•APP\Controller\InfoController.php line 399 → CakeEmail->send() 
•[internal function] → InfoController->coupon() 
•CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(InfoController, array) 
•CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 191 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest) 
•CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 165 → Dispatcher->_invoke(InfoController, CakeRequest) 
•APP\webroot\index.php line 108 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

as you can see, it asks for "paris_user.ctp".
Can anybody tell mee what's happening here? I fixed this by renaming my template from "parisUser.ctp" to "paris_user.ctp"...

I want to understand why Cake behaves like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cake 2.x view file names are still underscore separated.  That's really all there is to it.  The reason that your first email worked is that it conforms to the convention (by being a single word all lowercase).

From the book:

> View template files are named after the controller functions they display, in an underscored form.

[Here is the link.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#view-conventions)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm surprised that I never realized that. Thanks.